# How do I add a Remote Connection to Ionos Database for ExcelforMySQL?

Tags: mysql, excel-addins

I have a database that I have created for a friend of a mine that he would like to store his data and work directly from on a daily basis. Recently I came across ExcelforMySQL and thought this would be a perfect AddIn for him to use.

I have successfully linked the AddIn to the database (Xampp Local connection) and this loads up fine but when I move the database onto a webserver that I have with ionos(1and1) and enter the Host Details along with the Username and Password, I get the following error:

```
Connection attempt failed.
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

When I click Show Details:

```
All it says is One or more errors occurred.
```

Would really appreciate it, if somebody could advise on how to fix this, as I really want to be able to work live on the data and update the changes from the user directly in Excel if possible and this addin looks like it does that.

If anyone has any other suggestions then I am happy to hear them as not fussed as what is used as long as it works.

Thanks

Comment: Database credentials normally change completely when you move code to the live server

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, I have entered the correct details for the 1and1 database but get that error so not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem to yourself with a number of my own sites/DB's hosted on Ionos.  After a bit of searching through [their help they state](https://www.ionos.com/help/hosting/troubleshooting-mysql-databases/connection-and-access-problems-with-mysql-databases/) that access from outside your Ionos package is not possible.  Unfortunately we're stuck with their hosted version of PHP My Admin in the control panel.

Although I have found that MySQL-front works great and bypasses the Ionos restrictions.  Google is your friend...

Maybe a bit late for you but for others who come across this question as I said google is your friend...

Comment: I dont understand, how did youu fiix this?